# how to always show / persist tab bar in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

first off, here is the most basic possible code i can provide as an example (i tried making a snack and it refused to find the npm dependencies):

```js
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native'
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack'
import {Text, View} from 'react-native'

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator()
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()
const linking = {
    config: {
        screens: {
            Tabs: {
                screens: {
                    Home: '',
                    Feed: 'feed',
                },
            },
            Post: 'post',
        },
    },
}

export default function App() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer linking={linking}>
            <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen name="Tabs" component={Tabs} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
                <Stack.Screen name="Post" component={Post}/>
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}

function Tabs() {
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator>
            <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home}/>
            <Tab.Screen name="Feed" component={Feed}/>
        </Tab.Navigator>
    )
}

function Home({navigation}) {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Home</Text>
            <Text onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Post')}>Go To Post</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

function Feed({navigation}) {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Feed</Text>
            <Text onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Post')}>Go To Post</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

function Post() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Post</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

as you can see, a `Post` can be navigated to from the `Home` or `Feed` screens. please note the `linking`, as this is important for web.

i need the tab bar to always be visible because if someone visits a `Post` directly through their browser, there is no way for them to get back to the `Home` screen. for example, visit the `Post` screen from the `Home` screen by clicking the text, then refresh the page in the browser. the back arrow button will be gone but there will be no way to get back to `Home`.

i am not overly concerned with any tab having an active state when the `Post` screen is visited, as i know there is no way for the app to infer which tab should be active when a `Post` is visited directly. however, i need the tab bar to always be visible and i have spent so much time trying to figure this out already.

please note that nesting the screens will not work as it breaks the `linking` (there is an active github issue about this with no resolution as well).

how do i solve this? if i was just making a website, i would just have a layout file with my tab bar, and use that layout in all my screens. however, i am still new to react native so i can't figure this out. do i just scrap the react navigation tabs altogether and make my own tab bar implementation?

any help is appreciated

see aforementioned details

Comment: You could create a new ```Tab.Navigator``` that would be visible only on the ```Post``` screen, and you could set the buttons on in that Navigator to redirect to ```Home``` by using ```navigation.navigate('Post')``` or ```navigation.goBack()```.

Comment: @man517 that's not a bad idea i hadn't even thought of. thanks!